# Windows Phone Background Transfer Policies Transfer Limits

Tags: windows-phone-7, background-transfer

On [Background file transfers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) it says:

> Limits
>
> Maximum outstanding requests in the queue per application (this
>   includes active and pending requests): 25

But it seems that the Limit is 5. (According to my debugs and heaps of googling)

Is this OS version difference between 7.1 and 8.0?

If different versions have different limits is there away to get that maximum limit without hardcoding it?

Comment: Got answer? Same clarification is needed for me as well.

Comment: No answer yet. I have kept on going with assuming that limit is 5. Works for my purposes, but still some clarification on this would be great.

Answer (score 0):

you can read it here

[Background file transfers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202955%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)